# Passport-azure-ad in node donot redirect to microsoft login page when calling from Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular6, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I have an express app which logs me in with Microsoft using `passport-azure-ad`.

The Express app has a single view with a login button, when the user clicks on this button the `/login` endpoint is called.   This endpoint runs the `passport.authenticate` method that takes me to the Microsoft login page.

When I hit this endpoint from Angular 6 I received an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
>   (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'null' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.

It does not redirect me to the Microsoft login page.

The screen shots of my code

[image]

I receive the token and user logged in information from microsoft in this method after successful sign in.

[image]

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please paste your code in (and use the code formatting tool) instead of using screen shots from your IDE.

Comment: @Graham Thank you so much for your advice.